# My paper was accepted in Springer International Conference and National conference. What to do?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, masters

We had prepared the paper and applied for National Conference. After some days came to know about the International Conference and improved the paper and applied for it. After a month we got an accept mail from Springer Conference(Not expected as we are beginners). Today we presented our paper in the National Conference and our paper was selected as the Best Paper as well as got shortlisted for the International Journal. Now we are totally confused what to do ? Can we accept for publishing in the Journal but the Slight Modified (Improved) paper will be getting published in Springer Conference in July this year. Will this lead to any problem ?

This would help a lot in boosting our resume and also getting an Admit from Good University for my Masters.

Comment: This is why you NEVER simultaneously submit a paper!

Comment: We thought our paper might get rejected from International Conference. So applied for National Conference as we are final year Undergrad students. We may not get time(Or everyone will be busy with their corporate jobs ) to apply and publish in the next conferences.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: That's true in fields where conferences and papers are "tightly bound"; where this isn't so, it's not so big a deal.

Comment: I am surprised that this question has not got any up votes besides mine. While it is not a good situation to be in, I think it is an important question, that is reasonably well asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you can really do here is to contact the organizers and publishers of both journals, and indicate what is going on. More likely than not, you will need to withdraw one of the papers, as publishing both papers under very similar titles with identical scientific content (or very nearly so) is considered inappropriate.

Comment: At least in computer science, the most likely outcome — and the correct one — is that **both** submissions would be rejected.  (Or at least that would be the outcome if one of the conferences hadn't already happened.)

Answer (score 6):

**You *must* withdraw the second conference submission.**

Simultaneous submission of the same paper to multiple conferences or multiple journals is completely inappropriate.  If you do not withdraw, you run the very serious risk of having **both** submissions rejected and your invitation to the International Journal rescinded

> This would help a lot in boosting our resume and also getting an Admit from Good University for my Masters.

No, it wouldn't.  In the long run, publishing the same paper in multiple equivalent venues will only hurt you.  To put it bluntly, that's a form of academic fraud.  If I discovered that a graduate student in my department had done this, *even before they were admitted,* I would recommend immediate dismissal.

Comment: Oh ok ! I'm a beginner I didn't knew all these stuff thanks a lot. I will withdraw the national conference one.

Comment: @PradeepG How do you propose to withdraw a paper that has already been presented?

Comment: @David This was before presenting the paper. I had applied for 2 conferences and I got this doubt while deciding to select one conference.

Comment: @PradeepG I'm confused: your question says, "Today we presented our paper."

Comment: @David Hmmn :) My bad that was a long back ago. We had presented our paper but in that conference proceedings they did not publish the paper. Later they offered us to get the paper published in one of the International Journal which didn't happen.

Comment: @RameshSuresh It is excusable that you as a beginner did not know this, but it is inexcusable that your supervisor/mentor did not prevent this situation from happening. Duplicate submissions are considered a fraud at *expense of others*, since you wasted time of *two* sets of reviewers to get essentially the same answer (positive=your research is good). Reviewers are in high demand and the work is tedious so, yea, people have a reason to be angry about this.